# Codeigniter Driver: cannot access to parent method from subclasses

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to write a driver, and some methods are shared by subclasses. I want to implement that methods in the parent class.

I've read [here](http://kevinphillips.co.nz/news/codeigniter-drivers-tutorial/) that each propriety or function set to public/protected could be accessible by child classes.

So, in the parent class `Driver_name` i set `method_one` as protected, and when i try to access it by `Driver_name_subclass_one` error log says "No such method 'method_one'".

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to keep the method public. Drivers do not use standard class inheritance such as `class Cache_dummy extends Cache`, which is how you're used to it working and probably expect. Instead, it uses [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to find public methods from the parent and make them available to the individual driver through the use of the magic method `__call()`.

Here is a snippet of how this is done in CI, located in `system/libraries/Driver.php` in the `CI_Driver` class around line 136:

```
$r = new ReflectionObject($parent);

foreach ($r->getMethods() as $method)
{
    if ($method->isPublic())
    {
        $this->methods[] = $method->getName();
    }
}
```

The same goes for properties of the parent, such as `$CI` -- keep them public or they can't be "inherited" by the sub drivers.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i didn't know this method. Now i got it!

Answer (score 0):

Hello there and sorry for my late answer.
Have your tried using this:

`$this->_parent->method_one();`

This is useful if you want to access to parent's methods or even to siblings methods. Check the examples below:

```
class Driver_name extends CI_Driver_library
{
    public $ci;
    public $valid_drivers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->valid_drivers = array('child_one', 'child_two');
    }

    public function parent_method() {}
}
```

And we have two children:

```
// Child one
class Driver_name_child_one extends CI_Driver
{
    public function method_of_child_one() {}
}

// Child two
class Driver_name_child_two extends CI_Driver
{
    public function method_of_child_two() {}
}
```

It is obvious that if you to access a child's method from parent, you only need to do:

```
$this->child_one->method_of_child_one();
$this->child_two->method_of_child_two();
```

To access a parent method from a child, the method needs to be `public` and there are two ways to access:

```
// Option 1
$this->parent_method();

// Option 2
$this->_parent->parent_method();
```

If you want to access siblings methods, you have to use the `_parent` property like so:

```
// Child_one access Child_two method (inside Driver_name_child_one.php).
$this->_parent->child_two->method_of_child_two();

// Child two access Child_one method (inside Driver_name_child_two.php).
$this->_parent->child_one->method_of_child_one();
```